# non injective vector function

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $f:U\to R^m$ where $U$ is open in $R^n$. If $f$ is continuously differentiable why is $f$ never injective no matter what function it is? Here $n>m$ so $U$ is in a sense "much larger" than $R^m$

Comment: you need $n>m$ for any statement like this

Comment: Yes thank you! I fixed it

Comment: why is $f: U\to f(U)$ not possible to be a diffeomorphism exactly?

Comment: This is invariance of domain, anyway.  There are answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524150/show-that-a-smooth-map-f-mathbbrm-to-mathbbrn-for-mn-cannot-be-inje